# Auto search from google after coverting speech to text javascript

Tags: javascript, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

After some speech-to-text conversion into the $searchText variable, I show a button.

By clicking this button, you trigger a search from google.

However, I want to enter a text which automatically starts a search (without clicking on a button).

Example: If, after 3 seconds, $searchText is not empty, it searches automatically without clicking a button. I am a beginner. Can you help?

```js
$button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if ($searchText.value !== '') {
        var url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=' + $searchText.value;
        window.open(url, '_blank');
    }
});
```

Comment: Please mention if there are any errors or your expected output. What exactly you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I have added an input box for simplifying. I believe you want something like this.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
<!-- Your searchbox -->
<input type="text" id="searchText">

<script>
    let timerID = null;

    const $searchText = document.getElementById("searchText");
    $searchText.addEventListener('input', () => {

        clearTimeout(timerID)
        if (!$searchText.value) {
            return ;
        }

        timerID = setTimeout(() => {
            const url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=' + $searchText.value;
            window.open(url, '_blank');
        }, 3000 /* 3 seconds */) 

    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```